# How can I always fit div element to bottom of webpage with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, position, tailwind-css

I'd like to have the following the div element always fit to the bottom of my webpage (i.e. it'd act as a footer to my pages). Currently, it's near the bottom, but there's still a black space in between my element and the bottom of the webpage which I'd like to remove - I'm open to any other comments regarding my styling or structure as well. Thank you.

```
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1 items-end relative bottom-0 w-full">
      <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 1px">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 2px">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 3px">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="flex relative bg-white w-full h-20 items-center justify-center">
        <img src="../img/logo.png" class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 h-24"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Click here to see photo of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSfIz.png)

I've tried using relative and absolute positioning with Tailwind CSS - but I'm not too familiar with these classes, so I think it may be part of the issue.